# Updating a Bookmark in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

How do you update a bookmark in PowerBI?

Nothing I am doing seems to be working.

I use the selection pane to hide and unhide what I want, and then I click update on the bookmark but nothing happens.

Comment: Probably, this was a bugg that has been fixed. In the current version of Power BI Desktop, bookmarks can be updated exactly as stated by @Chicken-Sandwich-No-Pickles (select and hide/unhide in the selection pane; then, in the bookmark pane, click on the three dots of the bookmark you want to update).

Answer (score 2):

Bookmark work this way:

Select all filters that you want, show/hide elements from "Selection pane" then from bookmark click "ADD", change the name for readability;
Change your filter, change show/hide element from "Selection pane" then from bookmark click "ADD";

Now when we click "View" we should see that canvas is changing.

[image]

At this step (if everything work correctly), we can assign bookmark to button or image; We can do that by enabling action and changing the type to Bookmark.

[image]

Now, when I click on the button or image with "CTRL" (only desktop version), the view should switch to the one stored in the bookmark.